# In the context of quantum field theory, what does it mean to "couple" something?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, quantum-electrodynamics, interactions

Suppose I have the following Lagrangian density
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} = - \frac{1}{4} F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}
\end{equation} 
The lecture notes I an reading suggest if I want to "couple to matter", I would write a Lagrangian density such as
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} = - \frac{1}{4} F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} - j^{\mu}A_{\mu}
\end{equation} 
where $j^\mu$ is a function of matter fields.

**My Question:**

1. What does it mean to "couple"?  Why does coupling involve adding additional terms to the Lagrangian density?
2. When he says "couple to matter", what are we coupling? The electromagnetic field to the matter?

Comment: Do you know how to derive the equations of motion from the euler-lagrange equations?  You can get an intuition for the coupling of different degrees of freedom by working out the introduction of the coupling term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of Feynman diagrams, a "coupling" translates to a *vertex factor*. The Lagrangian for a free electromagnetic field is
$$\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{4}F^2$$
as you well know. Now suppose we have an electron field $\psi$ too. We want this electron field to "interact", or *couple*, with (to) the photon field. The free Dirac Lagrangian is
$$\mathcal{L}=\bar\psi(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m)\psi$$
We can construct from the Dirac equation the electron current
$$j^\mu\propto\bar\psi\gamma^\mu\psi$$
The proportionality constant is $e$, the electron charge. In a sense, $e$ describes the strength of the interaction between photons and electrons. The coupling term is $j_\mu A^\mu$ and thus the full Lagrangian is
$$\tag{1}\mathcal{L}=\bar\psi(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m)\psi-\frac{1}{4}F^2+e\bar\psi\gamma^\mu A_\mu\psi$$
It is also commonly written as
$$\mathcal{L}=\bar\psi(i\gamma^\mu D_\mu-m)\psi-\frac{1}{4}F^2,\quad D_\mu=\partial_\mu-ieA_\mu$$

So what do all these terms mean in terms of QFT? The first term in (1) gives
$$\frac{i}{\gamma^\mu p_\mu-m+i\epsilon}$$
which is the fermion propagator. The second term gives (after a Faddeev-Popov treatment)
$$\frac{i}{k^2+i\epsilon}\left[(1-\xi)\frac{k_\mu k_\nu}{k^2+i\epsilon}-\eta_{\mu\nu}\right]$$
which is the photon propagator.

The last term is a bit more tricky. It describes an electron interacting with a photon. This is represented by the vertex factor
$$ie\gamma^\mu$$
which describes one of four situations:

1. An electron emits a photon.
2. An electron absorbs a photon.
3. An electron annihilates with a position to form a photon.
4. A photon turns into an electron and a positron via pair production.

Comment: You are just writing down a Lagrangian and saying that's how you introduce an interaction term.  

Why don't you describe how the forcing term manifests from the Euler-Lagrange equation of the Lagrangian you are describing rather than just saying "this is what it is."

Comment: @user18764 Why don't you write up that idea into your own answer?

Comment: @user18764: What do you mean by "forcing term?"

Comment: @user18764: Do you mean show that the $j^\mu$ in the Lagrangian (1) is the same as the $\phi$ and $\mathbf{J}$ in Maxwell's equations?

Comment: When we plug the commonly written form as you call it of that Lagrangian into the Euler-Lagrange equations, what do we get?  What pops out? If you have already answered this, great just point out where. I'm just trying to clarify. Thanks for your elaborate answers.

Comment: For the $A_\mu$ equations, we get Maxwell's equations generated by the current $e\bar\psi\gamma^\mu\psi$. For the $\psi$ equations, we get the (conjugate of the) Dirac equation in an electromagnetic field. It's just the field equations, as usual.